# Installation error low-graphics mode multiple video cards

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, multiple-monitors

I am starting a brand new install and every time I go through the boot up process I get the message "running in low-graphics mode"
I click OK, which then gives you the 4 options:

run in low-graphics mode for just one session; 
reconfigure graphics; 
trouble shoot this error; 
exit to console login;

select run in low-graphics mode give you a message that graphics is going to restarts, but just hangs there after clicking ok (must ctrl-alt-del to restart - you see the normal unmounting [OK] etc. messages)

selecting reconfigure graphics gives you two options:
use default (generic) configuration; 
use your backed-up configuration; 
I chose use default and it just gets caught in a loop you can click ok 100 times and still just gives you the same options.  You hit cancel and it sends you back to the main menu

Troubleshoot this error allows you to look at the xlog where it says: 
Warning couldn't open module nvidia; then loaded module nouveua.  It does this 3 times once for each card.  Then it proceeds to load all the DVI interfaces DVI-1 - DVI-10 giving them the correct model for each monitor  detected and setting initial mode sizes for each.  Each monitor detected with proper model and serial number.  The Xlog then goes on to load the rest of the hardware mouse, keyboard, etc.
Last 3 lines of the log file read; 
AIGLX: Suspending AIGLX clients for VT switch; 
NOUVEAU(0):NVLeaveVT is called; 
Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file;

It gives an option to review start-up errors, but that is empty.  Also gives you an option to edit the configuration file which just throws in a loop again.  you just keep clicking OK.

Selecting the Last option: Exit to console login just blacks the screen and you must ctrl-alt-del (flashes to show unmounting) to restart the PC

The system has 3 NVIDIA cards NVS285 (dual dvi) and two (2) NVS 440 (quad dvi).  I have tried both the 12.04.3 as well as 13.10 and both hang on the same section.  Does anyone have an idea what is going on?  Being there was no errors in the X-Log I can not seem to find out why this is stuck here.

Comment: Have you tried pressing ctrl+alt+F1 to switch to a text monitor?

Comment: Have you tried the tips at ['How to fix “The system is running in low-graphics mode” error?'](http://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error) ?